# Using Osmdroid and OSM maps to create a navigation android app

Tags: android, algorithm, navigation, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have successfully made a sample app which loads an offline OSM map and displays it on the device. I followed the instructions at [here](http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30).

Now my aim is to create a navigation app for a building.(within the building). I am now moving to the tutorials given at [here](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/)

I am a newbie to android development. I am starting have doubts on whether i can implement the routing algorithms for a building navigation using OSM. This is what I plan to do:

1. Use KML to add overlays. This will be the map of the building.
2. Implement the routing algorithm.

I have got a vague idea about the 1st part. So far, i am clueless about the second one. I have the algorithm. To get the present location , i plan to use GPS.Next user has to select a tile in the map and the app will guide the user to it.

Experts, can you share some thoughts on how should i proceed. Any links,tutorials,sample apps, videos would be appreciated.

Comment: Am working with OsmDroid too for a few months. in my blog: http://mobiledevstories.wordpress.com i've posted some beginning tutorials, but am planning to upload a bigger one with deeper explainations. As far as im concerned, you can do step-by-step navigation easily using OsmBonusPack, but i haven't implemented it fully offline yet, only with internet available.

Comment: @voghDev... so how is it now? Could you share some tutorials for making the offline navigation ?

Comment: hi @gumuruh. I could not do the offline step-by-step navigation, and i'm afraid that this is not possible with OsmDroid. When you have internet is easy, for example with MapQuest API, because it queries the MapQuest server for the step-by-step instructions, but i didn't find an offline version of that.

Comment: no internet connection @voghDev.....
i thought it was offline navigation. sigh.